# Know the words meaning but not the sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

what does it mean 
"A conventional evening dress is worn in most instances, save where a ruff or frill is added to heighten the effect of the headgear."
any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you be more specific about which part of the sentence you are unclear on? (The use of 'save' in this sentence is as 'except')

Comment: thanks for helping, I know the meaning of the words individually but i can not understand what the sentence is saying.  if you retell it in simple way i will make it out, i guess. I'm really thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual type of clothing worn in the situation or context described is "conventional evening dress" - except when ruffs or frills are added to emphasise the headgear (tiara, hat, etc...).

Comment: thanks a lot,  so "save" means "except" . that's what i grasp of your explanation of this sentence. in most of the times or occasions, the clothes which is common is conventional evening dress, unless you want to emphasize your hat and therefore you would use ruffs and frills.